# How to install ZeroMQ on Windows 10?

Tags: windows

I need to install ZeroMQ (libzmq) on windows 10 which is running on a VirtualBox. On their [official website](https://zeromq.org/download/) there are zip files for Visual Studio but on [their github](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq) they mentioned that Windows10 is not supported.

I downloaded the zip file of "Visual Studio 15 2017 x64" and also installed `cygwin` and `cmake` but when I try to install it via `cmake` I get: `The source directory does not appear to contain CMakeList.txt`. This is true but there is a `zmq.h` inside that directory which I thought I should install via `cmake`. I also tried `make` exactly how I do it in linux with `C` files but that one also didn't work.

I have to mention that I don't want to use the ZMQ in Visual Studio. I need to connect a python program running in the host linux to Metatrader via ZMQ and the method that I am following (https://github.com/darwinex/DarwinexLabs/tree/master/tools/dwx_zeromq_connector/v2.0.1#installation) needs `libzmq` to be installed.

Can someone please help me with installing ZMQ on Windows10 either via `cmake` or Visual Studio?

Comment: Note that the linked issue talks about Windows 10 *ARM*. You are on x64 so that does not matter. You should be able to grab libzmq.dll either from the zipfile mentioned in the darwinex page or from one of the release packages on the zeromq site. On Windows it is important to match compiler versions of all libraries, so you should figure out which compiler was used for your Python installation and match that. If it is not on the zeromq site, you will need to install the appropriate compiler yourself and use something like conan or vcpkg to build libzmq yourself.

Comment: Getting these unix libraries built is never not a problem.  That's why they recommend the Windows' way, let somebody else do it for you.  Downloads [are here](https://zeromq.org/download/#windows).

Comment: @Botje thank you for your comment. You are right about the ARM, because that was the only Windows10 which I found I thought it is not compatible. Just one small question, since I want to run the python from the host (linux) does its compiler version still need to be matched with the windows one?

Comment: No, ZMQ is a network protocol like any other. The *client library* however, should be compiled with the compiler of whatever it is embedded in, whether that is Python or something else.